# flaskでno-such-tableとエラーが出る

Tags: python, flask

flaskとSQLAlchemyを使っています。 ユーザー情報をデータベースに登録しようとすると、指定したところと別の場所にデータベースのファイルが生成され、データはどこにも保存されていません。

app.pyのコードとディレクトリとデータベース構造、エラー文を添付します。

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# create the app
app = Flask(__name__)

# create the extension
db = SQLAlchemy()
# configure the SQLite database, relative to the app instance folder
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///project.db"
# initialize the app with the extension
db.init_app(app)


# テーブルを定義####################################################

class UserInfo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_info'
    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    User_Name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    Email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    Password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

class CommentInfo(db.Model):
    CommentID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Comment_Content = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    Comment_Create_Date = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

class ThreadInfo(db.Model):
    ThreadID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Thread_Name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    Thread_Content = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    Thread_Create_Date = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)


#Routing##########################################################

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('homepage.html', \
        homepage = True, \
        title = 'homepage.html')

@app.route('/threadpage/')
def threadpage():
    return render_template('threadpage.html', \
        threadpage = True, \
        title = 'threadpage.html')

@app.route('/threadcreate/')
def threadcreate():
    return render_template('thread_create.html', \
        thread_create = True, \
        title = 'thread_create.html')

# ユーザー情報をDBに登録
@app.route('/userlogin/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def userlogin():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_info = UserInfo(
            User_Name = "a", #request.form['User_Name'],
            Email = "b",     #request.form['Email'],
            Password = "c",  #request.form['Password']
        )
        db.session.add(user_info)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')#redirect(url_for('user_detail', id=user_info.id))
    else:
        return render_template('user_login.html', \
            user_login = True, \
            title = 'user_login.html')

# IDからDBのユーザー情報を取得して表示
@app.route("/user_<int:id>")
def user_detail(id):
        user_info = db.get_or_404(UserInfo, id)
        return render_template("user_detail.html", user_info=user_info)

@app.route('/userpage/')
def userpage():
    return render_template('userpage.html', \
        userpage = True, \
        title = 'userpage.html')


#おまじない###############################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

ディレクトリ構造

```
workdir
  blog
    app.py
    instance
      project.db <-これを使いたい
  instance
    project.db <- これが新規作成される、テーブルは作成されず
```

データベース構造

```
  comment_info
  thread_info
  user_info
    UserID
    User_Name
    Email
    Password
```

エラー

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1965, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 921, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: user_info

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)     
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     
  File "C:\Users\user\sixchan4\blog\app.py", line 69, in userlogin
    db.session.commit()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 554, in commit
    return self._proxied.commit()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1923, in commit
    trans.commit(_to_root=True)
  File "<string>", line 2, in commit
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^```
````

Comment: app.py の実行をする際のカレントディレクトリはどこになっていますか？

Comment: workdirです。workdirからblog内にあるapp.pyを指定して実行していました。
カレントディレクトリについて質問された後に、カレントディレクトリをblogに移して実行したところ、無事にデータの保存ができました。
nekketsuuuさん、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

**自己解決**

従来
カレントディレクトリをworkdirにした状態でblog/app.pyを指定して実行していた

解決方法
カレントディレクトリをblogにした状態でapp.pyを指定して実行する